# how can I override alias set in .bash_aliases

Tags: bash, alias

I like to use bash aliases to customize bash commands. Is there a way to override the bash alias settings, or should I rename the aliases to something different than the original command.

eg: my .bash_aliases includes

```
alias ls='ls -ltr'
```

If I want to only retrieve the file name, do I need to rename the alias to something other than 'ls'? Or is there another way?

Comment: I would have modified names for specialized aliases, so that scripts don't have unintended side effects. Thus ll for your list alias instead of ls. Look at some peoples .bashrc files for hints on how to do things.

Comment: Although @dogbane provided the "correct" answer to the question that I posted, yours is more practical and the one that I will probably use; also thanks for the advice to look at .bashrc files. any in particular that you would recommend?

Comment: @Michael: Aliases aren't carried forward (exported) into scripts.

Comment: @Michael, that is very helpful since that is how I will be using it

Comment: I looked at the .bashrc files of my local Unix gurus and I read up on shell scripting in the O'Reilly bash Cookbook http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596526788/

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Is there a source for this?

Comment: @HashimAziz: `help export` only mentions variables and functions. Note also, but unrelated to the foregoing, that alias expansion is off by default in scripts.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Add a `\` (backslash) before the command to disable the alias, like this:

`\ls`

This will invoke the original (un-aliased) `ls`.

**Example**:

```
$ ls #will invoke the alias
total 0
-rw-rw-r--    1 dogbane foo          0 Nov  3 16:04 c
-rw-rw-r--    1 dogbane foo          0 Nov  3 16:04 b
-rw-rw-r--    1 dogbane foo          0 Nov  3 16:04 a

$ \ls #will disable the alias
a  b  c
```

Comment: just what I wanted, more elegant than I expected - Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

you can use `/bin/ls` temporarily, or `` `which ls` ``