# grep "--exclude=" cancels "--include=" while file extensions filtering

Tags: bash, grep

I want to grep only header files in source code. And seems that it is well-known and [already solved problem](https://phprevolution.blogspot.com/2018/08/how-to-grep-files-in-linux-but-only.html), but `--include=` doesn't work for me:

```
$ grep -rnI --include=\*.h 'static volatile'
net/ipv4/ipconfig.c:174:static volatile int ic_got_reply __initdata;    /* Proto(s) that replied */
drivers/mtd/maps/sbc_gxx.c:83:static volatile int page_in_window = -1; // Current page in window.
drivers/parport/parport_mfc3.c:79:static volatile int dummy; /* for trigger readds */
^C
```

I expect that there will be only header files with `.h` extension.
By the way, `--exclude=` works fine:

```
$ grep -rnI --exclude=\*.c 'static volatile'
arch/mips/include/asm/mach-pmcs-msp71xx/msp_gpio_macros.h:63:static volatile u32 * const MSP_GPIO_DATA_REGISTER[] = {
arch/mips/include/asm/mach-pmcs-msp71xx/msp_gpio_macros.h:83:static volatile u32 * const MSP_GPIO_MODE_REGISTER[] = {
arch/arm/mach-w90x900/include/mach/uncompress.h:28:static volatile u32 * const uart_base = (u32 *)UART0_PA;
arch/arm/mach-gemini/include/mach/uncompress.h:19:static volatile unsigned long * const UART = (unsigned long *)GEMINI_UART_BASE;
^C
```

**UPD:**

```
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.27
...

$ type grep
grep is aliased to `grep --color --exclude=tags --exclude-dir="build*"'
```

But it works well when alias is cancelled such way: `$ \grep -rnI --include=\*.h 'static volatile'`.
So why does `--exclude=` cancels `--include=`?

Comment: Please post the version of grep used, GNU or other

Comment: Also see if you have an alias defined for `grep`. Post the output of `type grep`. Because I can't seem to reproduce your problem

Comment: @Sundeep I did it just in Linux kernel sources directory on my Linux machine

Comment: @Inian grep is aliased to `grep --color --exclude=tags --exclude-dir="build*"'

Comment: what happens if you use `\grep -rnI --include=\*.h 'static volatile'` (note the \ at the beginning)

Comment: @Sundeep It works fine! What does it mean? It cancels alias?

Comment: okay, exclude=tags means `skip files and directories matching tags` which will mean files not named `tags` will now be in output.. for a better example, `exclude='*.c'` means exclude files ending in `.c` which means all other files will be matched.. so it is not canceling include.. just one of the rules to filter

Comment: @Sundeep You can post answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For alias overriding, see: [how can I override alias set in .bash_aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088357/how-can-i-override-alias-set-in-bash-aliases)

I couldn't find documentation relating to how multiple include/exclude rules affect the final list of files chosen for matching. But I think it is safe to assume that in case of conflict, the rule defined latest in the command line wins.

- `--exclude=tags` will ignore any file or directory whose name is exactly `tags`
- `--include='*.h'` will allow any file ending with `.h` to be matched

In this case, there is no conflict between the two rules. The first one allows `grep` to choose any file not named `tags`. The second one tells `grep` to allow any file ending with `.h`

In case of a conflict like `--exclude='*foo.txt' --include='*.txt'` the **include** rule will override the **exclude** rule and a file ending with `foo.txt` will be considered for matching